# Chosen not defined with backbone using browserify

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, browserify, jquery-chosen

I am trying to use chosen with backbone and browserfy. I have the chosen code included as a script tag in the main html page I am using. One of the views contained within that page has function called by an event:

```
events: {
    'click #createButton': 'createButtonClicked'
},

createButtonClicked: function() {
    this.$('#outputDialog').html(outputEditorTemplate());
    $("#outputTypeSelect").chosen({ disable_search_threshold: 10 });
    this.$('#outputDialog').modal('show');
},
```

I am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function`

I have also tried to include jQuery and us that over the `this.$()` function, and got the same error.

I have tried to follow the recommendations of overriding my window.jQuery [here](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/1433), but that breaks other portions of the page.

```
var $ = require('jquery');

// Chosen requires this :(
window.jQuery = $;

require('path/to/bower_components/chosen_v1.3.0/chosen.jquery');
```

Is there a way to get chosen without overriding the jQuery I use (window.jQuery)?

Comment: are you using require.js ...? or is `require` coming from browserify..? I'm not familiar with it and don't see a require tag hence asking

Comment: it comes from browserify